# how do I get contents of BLOB url in csv in php?

Tags: csv, curl, import, server, blob

How to import data from blob url to csv using curl. Basically I have a vendor who has shared us the blob url which we download and again reupload in our sales tool. using curl how to import entire data in csv on server so that it can be automated for inserting those rows in our sales tool

i tried with filegetcontents but it did not work. Searched in various blogs, but everywhere its shown how to import image.

Comment: Please someone help.

Comment: Could you please expand on why it does not suffice for you just to download the file from the blob url like this: `curl <blob-url> --output <csvfilename.csv>`

Comment: Nothing happens. Neither the data gets downloaded nor there is any error. What will be the code between <?   ?>